# Are escape pods placed at strategic locations around the Enterprise?

Tags: star-trek, uss-enterprise, star-trek-beyond

In *Star Trek: Beyond* I noticed that Kirk ejects directly from the bridge when the Enterprise is going to crash.

Does he have the only escape pod that ejects from the bridge? Is is so he can give final orders on the bridge before ejecting?

Surely there is not enough room on the bridge for all the crew. Do other key members of the crew have their escape pods at their respective stations?

I would expect to find Bones' pod in the sickbay.

Do the enlisted crew have their pods down below or perhaps at a muster area?

Comment: The 'Kelvin' pod is exclusive to the ship's bridge (e.g. so the captain doesn't have to go down with the ship for want of an easy escape route). Everyone else has to make do with calling it a boring plain old 'escape pod'. It seems roomy enough to fit a few crew and there seem to be **several of them** under the bridge.